# TFS repository cloning history

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

Is there any way to determine the number of the clients who cloned a certain project from the `TFS` repository? or even to reach the cloning history for example?. If this is applicable, please kindly provide the steps.

Comment: No, it's not possible. TFS does not carry "traffic" information like Github does so it's lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Stan mentions. No TFS doesn't track this history. You can parse the IIS logs (as long as SSH isn't configured) if you have them or access the `tbl_command` in the database to access raw command data for your TFS instance in the last x days.

That's the closest you'll be able to get.